# How to compare timestamps in tezos smartpy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

req passed to _verifySigPersonalSign will be of type ERC

```
import smartpy as sp

ERC = sp.TRecord(sender=sp.TAddress,to=sp.TAddress,deadline=sp.TTimestamp)

class StoreValue(sp.Contract):
    @sp.entry_point
    def _verifySigPersonalSign(self,params):
        req=params.req
        sp.verify(sp.now<=sp.timestamp(params.req.deadline))
```

But I am getting this error in the last line of code

```
Error: Error in Scenario
Literal format error: (timestamp(attr(attr(params 39)req 40)deadline 41))
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare timestamps, you can use `<` or `<=`.

The problem in your code is that `sp.timestamp(params.req.deadline)` is wrongly built. `sp.timestamp(...)` is for *constants*.

Simply replace that by `sp.now<=params.req.deadline`.